# Error 1009 cannot access a property----again

Tags: actionscript-3, text, error-handling

Hello I'm stuck on this one which is trying to show a game level on the game and getting an output error 1009.   I'm doing something wrong but can't figure.  Here is the code:

```
                                    if ( levelNumber ==1) {
                    var level:Number = 1;
                    showLevel.text=level.toString();
                    showLevel.text = String ("Level:     " +level);


                if ( levelNumber ==2) {
                    var level:Number = 2;
                    showLevel.text=level.toString();
                    showLevel.text = String("Level:     " +level);
                    var numBombs:Number = 4;

                }else if( levelNumber ==3 ) {
                    var level:Number = 3;
                    showLevel.text=level.toString();
                    showLevel.text = String ("Level:     " +level);
```

The debugger says it's the line with showLevel.text=level.toString();  which I have set as a Number ie private var level:Number =0.  I hope this is sufficient code to let you know what's going on here. It's also coming up with a duplicate variable definition - compiler error on var level:Number =2 and the next one that =3.Thanking you in advance for any assistance.  Cheers.

Comment: Do you have debugger available? Set breakpoint on problem line and see what's going on. From this code I can't tell what type showLevel is. Also, declare `var level` before if/else - ActionScript doesn't have block-scoped locals, hence duplicate definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Error #1009 is indeed a null reference error. I see your level is declared and has a right value.
Maybe the point is that your showLevel object (I guess it's a label) is not declared yet.

The problem can be that you use:

```
private var showLevel:mx.controls.Label;
```

instead of:

```
private var showLevel:mx.controls.Label = new mx.controls.Label();
```

otherwise if you make your showLevel in a viewStack you must be sure that your content is created yet. Therefor you can use:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="yourView" creationPolicy="all">
```

Comment: I'm so sorry but your answer proved too advance for me.  I have settled for the inability to produce different levels of the game at this time.  Hopefully in the near future I will get over this hurdle.

Comment: Is there something you want me to explain in a better way?